# Serialize enum as a string in JSON.NET using attributes

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to serialize enum as string using JSON.NET using attributes similar to `[JsonIgnore]`

Example class:

```
enum Gender { Male, Female }
class ABC
{
    public Gender { get; set; }
}
```

If I serialize this using JSON.NET:

```
var a = new ABC();
var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a);
```

`str` is set to `{Gender:0}` and I would prefer `{Gender:Male}`.

Comment: I don't quite understand what 'this' is - can you describe in more detail what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MiMo I'd updated my question to make it more clear. Please look

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]`. Should do what you want.

**Edit:** http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter.htm provides some info.